# JavaScript; trying to fire a click within a <ul> and <li id> and <a href> but not till the <li id> is called

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry if this is such a 'newbe' question, been fighting this for a while...

Seeking to fire an `<a href>` from within a tag.

Found several ways to do it, however.. the entire script is with-in an `<ul>`, so script to "click" the `<a href>` occurs on load of `index.html`, not when the specific tag is called.

Sorry if confusing; here are some snippets of code that may help explain.

```
<ul id="menu">
<!-- several <li> to other parts of the site, then: -->
<li>
    <a href="#!/WORKHISTORY" onclick="ga('send','event','Internal Links','Work History')">
      <span class="over"></span>
      <span class="txt1">Work History</span>
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Followed by:
an `<article>` and a `<ul>`

Within the `<ul>`, is a tag referencing the "workhistory" tag.

```
<li id="WORKHISTORY">
 <div class="box">
  <a id=wrkhst1 href="/gallery/1426894494/1426894576.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[1426894494]">
    <span class="over"></span>
  </a>
 </div>
</li>
```

I have tried to use `<script>document.getElementById('wrkhst1').click();</script>`
Which works, however it fires at the load of index.html, not with the click of the parent `<li>`, as it reads the main index page and loads it.

I tried the same script this in the  and not using the tag, but same result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an eventhandler, for the onclick-event, on the `li` element. There you simulate the click on the `<a>` tag.

In code it could look like:

```
document.querySelector('#WORKHISTORY').onclick = function(){
    document.querySelector('#wrkhst1').click();
};
```

**BUT** there are very few scenarios where this is needed. I'm sure in your case it would be better to make the `<a>` `display: block;` and set it to the size of the `<li>`. So `<a>` can do for what it was made for, without any need of javascript.

Comment: I apologize, but I am not sure what you rare suggesting for the size of the li. I am just working my way through HTML5, so lots to learn.  any help is appreciated.  what would the code look like?

Comment: You would do it with some CSS rules. I can't give you the right code because I don't know how the styling of your page is. But have a look at following example. In the first `li` only the text is clickable, in the second you can click on the whole area of the `li` (red background) because the `a` is using the entire space. Just because I told em to behave like a block element. http://jsfiddle.net/9sw0czaz/

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you are saying.  I already have the css controls in place via the div class, so I could just add it there.  However I will guess I will still needed to try the eventhandler.  I will experiment today.  Thank you for the time and responses.